# CGI script runs when called directly, but not when it's the index

Tags: fastcgi, bugzilla

Having never worked with CGI before (I'm a PHP person, really), I'm confused as to why my installation of Bugzilla won't display the index page correctly.

Before you ask:

- libapache2-mod-fastcgi is installed on the machine
- I have ExecCGI enabled for the directory in question
- I added .cgi as a handler as a cgi-script

When I access the script directly (by going to index.cgi), the script parses and renders correctly. When accessing the web root, the contents of index.cgi are displayed in plain text.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add index.cgi to the DirectoryIndex list:

```
DirectoryIndex index.cgi
```

If you have some sort of redirect from / to index.cgi, remove it with this statement in effect.  I have not tested this, but this is how I used to handle index.php on my system, back when I used php.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I used to have that problem with PHP, but I solved it so long ago, that I didn't even think it was the same problem! Heh.